# OpenCover- Open cover saying missing PDBs when working with vstest.console.ex in tfs build definiton

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, opencover, vstest

I am trying to integrate Opencover with TFS2013 for custom code coverage. I am passing the parameters necessary for running Open Cover via build definiton nad invoking OC using a InvokeProcess activity in the build process template.

I am following the procees mentioned in 
[this blog](http://yasuo.hatenablog.com/entry/2012/01/01/094202) , [here](http://yasuo.hatenablog.com/entry/2012/01/02/011606) and [here](http://yasuo.hatenablog.com/entry/2011/12/31/221216).

The final OpenCover arguments passed are

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user  -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"  -targetargs:"<build_definition_folder>\bin\NUnitTestDemo.dll <build_definition_folder>\bin\UnitTest.dll  /Platform:X86 /Framework:Framework45 /Logger:trx "  -targetdir:"<build_definition_folder>\bin"  -mergebyhash  -output:"<build_definition_folder>\bin\results.xml"
```

The output is coming as

Total tests: 2. Passed: 2. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

Test Run Successful.

Test execution time: 0.6657 Seconds

Committing...

No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:

1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
guide and the -register switch.

Please help me. The PDBs are present in the same bin folder only. I tried running Open cover locally in my machine with [Open Cover UI](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688) and it is giving the results well. but with console application it is not working as i expected in the build server.

Comment: Are you using powershell?

Comment: @iikkoo no i am using batch files. is there a problem with that. ? the parameters to OC console are obtained in runtime using stdouput. and i feel all paramters are passed correctly. still confusing why it is not working

Comment: Try and place the quotes around targetargs like this: "-targetargs:<text here>".

Comment: @iikkoo tried it. but it's of no use .. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this issue before and it was because my build service is running with "Network Service" account. After I changed it to run with an administrator account, it works correctly, result is generated successfully.

My fix:
Stop the build service and change the settings in "Properties" to run the service as an Administrator account. And then start the build service and queue a new build.[image]